# Shell script to email results of SQLPlus query using Mailx in AIX

Tags: shell, sqlplus, aix, mailx

I have the commands that I need. If I execute these commands at the prompt, everything works as expected. SQLPlus runs the query, exports the result to a file and then Mailx emails that file to me.

```
sqlplus username/pwd@instance
SPOOL /home/sadmin/sqlmail/spool.out
set linesize 2000
set wrap off
@/home/sadmin/sqlmail/query.sql
SPOOL OFF
exit
mail -s "Subject" email@address.com < /home/sadmin/sqlmail/spool.out
```

But, I can not, for the life of me, figure out how to put these in an .sh file so that I can schedule it. Help!? And thanks in advance, I'm sure this is very silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a shell 'Here' document is the usual solution, i.e.

```
 cat MyCommand.sh
 #!/bin/bash  # (or ksh, sh, etc)
 PATH=.../path/to/sqlplusdir:${PATH}

sqlplus username/pwd@instance <<EOS
    SPOOL /home/sadmin/sqlmail/spool.out
    set linesize 2000
    set wrap off
    @/home/sadmin/sqlmail/query.sql
    SPOOL OFF
    exit
EOS
mail -s "Subject" email@address.com < /home/sadmin/sqlmail/spool.out
```

You'll need to set  your PATH env to include the path to you sqlplus executable.

Then you need a userID with access to the cron facility. Do you know how to use the 'vi' editor? When you call `crontab`, you will be looking at the current users scheduled jobs and you will need to manipulate the file with 'vi' commands. (It may be possible to override which editor to use, but not recommended)

You need to read the man page for cron, i.e. `man cron`, and you will be call the above a a complete script. A cron entry will look like

```
59 23 31 12 * { var=x; export var ; myCommand ; } > /tmp/myWorkDir/myCommand.trace 2>&1 

min
   hr
     day
       mon
          (DayOfWeek)
```

values for date/times can be comma separated lists (0,15,30,45), hyphen separated ranges (4-6) or * to indicate all valid values.

This captures any output including stderr, from the 1 time run of myCommand into the file in the tmpDir.

The bare minimum version of the above would be

```
59 23 12 31 * var=x; export var ; myCommand
```

and then any output is sent to the user's local mailbox.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not so much concerned with the scheduling as I am with getting these commands into a .sh that I can execute. After I have the .sh, I can schedule it no problem.

If I just paste these files into a .sh and run it, I end up with a SQL> prompt. How to I get the SQLPlus commands to execute automatically within the .sh?

Comment: Also note that searching for 'sqlplus here document' here on S.O. shows other people using `sqlplus -s ...`. My experience has been with Sybase isql, so I am relying on what others have recommended when it comes to proper arguments/options for sqlplus. Good luck.