# Script to parse XML and download a file from certain URL then transfer it to another computer

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, xsd

I need a master computer to be able to download a predefined XML file then parse it; with the available info, a script should identify the correct file to be downloaded from a web server periodically. Finally this file must be transferred to another computer without internet access in the same LAN and extract it to a given location.

However I have bounds: I can't use PHP to accomplish this because and I can't install anything there; I've proposed to do this via MD5sums but a given day and hour must be given to be able to download the file to the master computer and another hour and day to transfer it to the slim terminal.

I've designed this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<updateXML id="subdirectory1">
    <file>
        <tarname>compressedFile.tar.gz</tarname>
        <name>fileInsideName</name>
        <filExtension>.ext</filExtension>
        <url protocol="http://">someurl.com/mainDirectory</url>
    </file>
    <update>
        <download>2012-02-02T03:00:00.00000</download>
        <copyTo terminal="1">2012-02-02T09:00:00.00000</copyTo>
    </update>
</updateXML>
```

And this working XML Schema (XSD)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="updateXML">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
            
                <xsd:element name="file" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:all>
                            <xsd:element name="tarname" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="filExtension" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="url">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:simpleContent>
                                        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:attribute name="protocol" type="xsd:string" />
                                        </xsd:extension>
                                    </xsd:simpleContent>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:all>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                
                <xsd:element name="update" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="download" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                            <xsd:element name="copyTo">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:simpleContent>
                                        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:attribute name="terminal" type="xsd:int" />
                                        </xsd:extension>
                                    </xsd:simpleContent>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>

            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I've researched and I've found XMLlint can parse XML files. No problems here now:

```
$ xmllint --noout --schema updatemenus.xsd updatemenus.xml 
updatemenus.xml validates
```

I've thought in a process that can help me accomplish the given task. I am keen to know if my proposed steps are correct:

1. Generate the XML and validate it with it's XSD.
2. Download it to the master computer and parse it there. Use the available info to construct a complete URL to download.
3. Once downloaded secure copy it to the needed terminal in the LAN
4. Check if a newer XML it's available and download it (a cron process?)

Is this correct? If so, now that my XML is valid, now what?
How can I use its info? I'm new to XMLlint and to XPath. What can I do now?

Comment: Can you FTP? What platform are you on? Do you have CRON or Scheduled Tasks available?

Comment: @mmcglynn Thanks for answering ;) I can't FTP. The files to be downloaded and the XML must reside in a webserver. I'm working on Linux Ubuntu (the slim clients have have Lubuntu). There are crons tasks available in the master computer (the middle one!) and all this it's supposed to be done via a cron task =/ I'm clueless really... =(

Comment: Well, CRON looks more complicated than it is, and there are LOTS of example, since this stuff has been around forever. You can do it!

Comment: @mmcglynn Thanks I'll do my best <=) It's a little complicated because of the time remaining for me to finish this. I'm more experienced with PHP and CSS =P this is different.
Now I'm trying to see what to do next with the parsed XML u.u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help with the whole thing, but you'll find dateTime in

```
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd
```

**edit**

my point is that your document specifies

```
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

which is an existing document BUT not a true .xsd file and will not validate any of your XML.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @shelter Thanks for helping me, don't worry. Yes I know this, thanks. If I check my XSD against this URL you gave me, there are no problems: `xmllint --noout -schema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd updateFiles.xsd 
updateFiles.xsd validates` However as said in my post, if I check my XML against my valid XSD I got that error... What could be the reason? u_u THANKS!

Comment: @shelter Thanks but maybe I didn't understand correctly =( I've added to the URL the .xsd extension, and I even downloaded the whole XMLSchema.xsd and tried to validate against it, but it's the very same behavior =(

Comment: @shelter I found the error! =D the problem was in my XSD. I just wrote `type="dateTime"` but it should have been `type="xsd:dateTime"`
Thanks anyway...

NOW WHAT? U__U I've parsed the XML, now how can I use it? =(

Comment: For some info on crontab, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284149/shell-script-to-email-results-of-sqlplus-query-using-mailx-in-aix/6284497#6284497 Good luck.